# team work with codename one

Tags: codenameone, gitignore

i am a student and i am a member of a group of five...
We have to work in the same project using git and we are using Scrum method in our work, so , we need some guide and best practice and answers before starting...we will be so happy with your informations.
 can we use différent IDE (intellij and Netbeans)... if yes, the .gitinore file will contains every IDE 's specefic .gitignore file?

Comment: You have asked three separate questions here, and none are appropriate for SO. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to get started: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-using-git-for-codename-one-projects.html

e.g. sample gitignore from https://github.com/codenameone/MaterialScreensUIKit

```
*.jar
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
lib/CodenameOne_SRC.zip

psds/.DS_Store
.DS_Store
```

In your theme editor make sure the `File` -> `XML Team Mode` is checked for everyone so you can work on XML and individual files rather than the whole thing.

Alternatively you can avoid the designer tool altogether and [use CSS](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-css-to-import-images.html).

Comment: Thank you for these infos. You wrote: «In your theme editor make sure the File -> XML Team Mode is checked for everyone so you can work on XML and individual files rather than the whole thing». But in the page you linked you wrote: «the simulator/device are oblivious to this mode. So if you fetch an update you also need to update the res file and you might still have conflicts related to that file». Have you considered to implement an option to update the .res file according to the content of the /res folder?

Comment: That's the option. If you open the designer and save the res file will be updated with the correct values from the res folder.

Comment: Hi, thank you Mr. we are going well, now we have a vertical navigation works well, so every one in the team can select his SideMenuElement and he get his first form, now, we need to move horizontally, without loose the Resources object... can you advice us to do that ?
And thank you very much, for your great cd1 and for your good service :)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand that question? The resource file gets lost during merges. You can look at this answer that covers updating the resource file automatically from XML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010241/insert-data-in-codename-one-resource-file-in-command-line-or-directly