# Insert data in codename one resource file in command line or directly

Tags: codenameone

I’am currently write an application and i need to put a content directly in the resource file (theme.res). How can I achieve this? What about the binary format of the resource file?

Is it possible to achieve the same thing with the use of CodenameOne designer tool in command line? I want to put a localization bundle in the RES file with my custom app. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `XML Team Mode` flag in the designer tool and save. Once you do that you will see an XML file and a hierarchy next to it in the `res` directory. This will be used by the designer tool but is invisible to the build process.

You can use the following in the latest designer tool:

```
java -jar /path/to/designer_1.jar -sync-xml /path/to/theme.res
```

This updates the res file from the XML.

Alternatively you can add this to the `build.xml` so it's automated:

```
<taskdef name="syncXML" classname="com.codename1.build.client.SyncXMLTask" classpath="CodeNameOneBuildClient.jar"/>
```

Then use this in some place to regenerate the res file:

```
<syncXML/>
```

Comment: Hi Shai,  
Is it not possible to activate the XML Team Mode with command line too. I don’t want the user of the app to go into the designer and to check it manually. I just want to click on a button in my app and to have my content inserted into the RES file. For that I will use your command line solution.  
My problem now is to know how i can activate this XML Team Mode in the designer with command line too?  
Thanks for the command line to updates the RES file from the XML but it’s not complete.

Comment: That's a single time process of activating this. If it's not active you would be overriding the content of the res file which you probably don't want.

Comment: Hi Shai ! I know this is a single time process to activate this but i really want to simplify the life of the user . Is it not possible to add this command to the designer?  To allow the activation of the XML Team Mode to the designer? If not, can you tell me more about the binary format of the RES file so I can put data directly inside using the binary way? I really don't need the user to do another action outside my app like go to activate manually the XML team mode even if it's a single time process. Thanks

Comment: The binary format of the res file is all in the repository. You can use Resources.java for reading and EditableResources.java for writing. Since the full Codename One Designer is open source you can just look